# can fusion chart x axis be represinted by points instade of labels

Tags: java, smartgwt, label, fusioncharts

as known  Fusion charts takes the x axis points as labels with an equal spaces between, but i want to give the x axis a real numbers with a real spaces between them.

so can i use real points in fusion charts instead of labels ?
now it is like this :

15

12

9

6

3

0   1_**10**_11 **_1 2**_90

but i want make it with variable distance x axis intervals like this :

12

9

6

3

0

1 **_ 2  *_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** 10 **_ 11  *_*_** 15

i want the values or labels to has a real distances .
thanx.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do this is to pad your data with the missing values and hide those labels.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can conclude, you want a numeric x-axis along with a numeric y-axis. This sort of charts are XY plots. In FusionCharts suite, you may consider using [scatter chart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#bubble-and-xycharts).

Using scatter chart you can even plot line chart. There is a forum post elaborating the use of [`drawLine` attribute on FusionCharts `dataset` node of scatter chart](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/4201-line-chart-in-scatter-xy-chart/?p=15476).

Sample `XML` data for Scatter chart with connecting line:

[image]

```xml
<chart palette='2' anchorradius='6' anchorsides='0'>
   <categories>
        <category x='1' label='1' />
        <category x='2' label='2' />
        <category x='10' label='10' />
        <category x='11' label='11' />
        <category x='15' label='15' />
    </categories>

   <dataset drawLine='1' seriesName='Server 1'>
      <set y='2.4' x='1' />
      <set y='3.5' x='2' />
      <set y='2.5' x='10' />
      <set y='4.1' x='11' />
      <set y='3.5' x='15' />
   </dataset>

   <dataset drawLine='1' seriesName='Server 2'>
      <set y='1.4' x='1'/>
      <set y='1.5' x='2'/>
      <set y='1.5' x='10'/>
      <set y='1.1' x='11'/>
      <set y='1.5' x='15'/>
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

However, if you intend to draw columns, you would need to insert blank `category` nodes to emulate the same.

Sample `XML` data for multi-series charts:
[image]

```xml
<chart showValues='0' numberPrefix='$'>
   <categories>
      <category label='1' />
      <category label='2' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='10' />
      <category label='11' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='' />
      <category label='15' />
   </categories>
   <dataset seriesName='2006'>
      <set value='27400' />
      <set value='29800'/>
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='31900' />
      <set value='34800' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='31800' />
   </dataset>
   <dataset seriesName='2005'>
      <set value='10000'/>
      <set value='11500'/>
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='22900' />
      <set value='20800' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='' />
      <set value='19700' />
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

The above sample should allow you to create similar data in any other chart.

Comment: you are welcome. One quick tip: You can write a small javascript snippet to intercept `BeforeDataUpdated` event on chart and automatically pad null values.

Comment: i have another problem, can please help me again ?
i posted another qustion with my problem here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214046/fusion-chart-x-axis-values-not-like-expected