# FusionCharts: X-axis values not like expected

Tags: java, xml, charts, fusioncharts

I am using FusionCharts but I'm facing some problems. I get 0 on X-axis at index not 0 (I marked it in a red color) on the the snapshot below.

Another problem is that the line is not drawn?

This is the figure i get :
[image]

This is my XML code:

```
    <chart caption="" xaxisname="Quantity (finished items)" yaxisname="Cost" numdivlines="9" lineThickness="2" showvalues="0" showLegend="1" canvasPadding="0" legendIconScale="1.4" numVisiblePlot="15">
<categories>
<category  x="0" label="0"/>
<category  x="5000" label="5000"/>
<category  x="10000" label="10000"/>
<category  x="15000" label="15000"/>
<category  x="20000" label="20000"/>
<category  x="25000" label="25000"/>
<category  x="30000" label="30000"/>
<category  x="35000" label="35000"/>
<category  x="40000" label="40000"/>
<category  x="45000" label="45000"/>
<category  x="50000" label="50000"/>
<category  x="55000" label="55000"/>
<category  x="60000" label="60000"/>
<category  x="65000" label="65000"/>
<category  x="70000" label="70000"/>
</categories>
<dataset seriesName="Flow Name" drawLine="1 " anchorSides="20" anchorRadius="5">
<set x="0" y="169.13"/>
<set x="5000" y="9046.95"/>
<set x="10000" y="17924.78"/>
<set x="15000" y="26802.6"/>
<set x="20000" y="35680.42"/>
<set x="25000" y="44558.25"/>
<set x="30000" y="53436.07"/>
<set x="35000" y="62313.9"/>
<set x="40000" y="71191.72"/>
<set x="45000" y="80069.54"/>
<set x="50000" y="88947.38"/>
<set x="55000" y="97825.2"/>
<set x="60000" y="106703.02"/>
<set x="65000" y="115580.84"/>
<set x="70000" y="124458.66"/>
</dataset>
<dataset seriesName="B1" drawLine="1 " anchorSides="3" anchorRadius="5">
<set x="0" y="123.16"/>
<set x="5000" y="271.37"/>
<set x="10000" y="419.59"/>
<set x="15000" y="567.8"/>
<set x="20000" y="716.02"/>
<set x="25000" y="864.23"/>
<set x="30000" y="1012.45"/>
<set x="35000" y="1160.66"/>
<set x="40000" y="1308.88"/>
<set x="45000" y="1457.09"/>
<set x="50000" y="1605.31"/>
<set x="55000" y="1753.52"/>
<set x="60000" y="1901.73"/>
<set x="65000" y="2049.95"/>
<set x="70000" y="2198.16"/>
</dataset>
</chart>
```

Comment: How are you generating fusion charts. Are you passing values with some manipulation or it is hard coded.

Comment: You need to provide more information like - what chart type is that? Can you put up the screenshot with sample data and its data XML/JSON? E.g a column chart will not start showing labels from the edge.

Comment: The XML data format that you have used is of the Scatter chart which is displaying the data correctly on the chart.In case you are trying to render a Multi-series Line chart, you would need to use the data format supported by the Multi-series Line chart.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `chartType` you are selecting is not `Scatter` (inferring from screenshot, it is `MSColumn2D` or some other Multi-series Column chart). Wherever in your code you are doing `new FusionCharts(/*...*/);`, try changing the chart type to `Scatter`. Refer to [the FusionCharts documentation link explaining how to change chart type](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/FirstChart/ChangeChart.html)

Comment: You are welcome. Just a note that you need to mark answers as accepted (the check mark under the answer vote buttons) if the answer had helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try setting "**canvasPadding**" attribute to **'0'** in the `<chart>` element of the XML and see if that helps?